# Mysql: Find rows, where timestamp difference is less than x

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got table structure as follows:

```
Field       Type
id              int(11)      AI
user            varchar(64)
date            timestamp
key             int(11)
```

What I need to do, is find rows (from given day), where difference between two successive rows (closest timestamp (for given user) is less than 1300.

I was told, to use query like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, @nextdate as nextdate, @nextdate := date
      from my_table t
      order by date desc
     ) t
where t.nextdate - t.date < 1300;
```

But it didn't seem to work. Can anyone help me solve my task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL datetime comparison with previous row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079190/mysql-datetime-comparison-with-previous-row)

Comment: try using `order by user,date desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
select t1.user, t1.date d1,t2.date d2 ,t1.date-t2.date
  from  (select @val:=@val+1 rowid,user,  date
           from mytable,(select @val:=0) a
       order by user,date) t1,

        (select @val1:=@val1+1 rowid,user,  date
           from mytable,(select @val1:=1) b
       order by user,date) t2

 where t1.rowid = t2.rowid
   and t1.user = t2.user
   and t1.date-t2.date < 1300;
```

see [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/6af1c/8)

Answer (score 1):

DATEDIFF(t.netxdata, t.date) < (1300 / 3600 / 24)
I assumed 1300 in in seconds, so I converted it to days which is what DATEDIFF returns.
Please, be aware that this query will do a full scan of your table, which might be expensive.

Comment: Hmm... In Phpmyadmin I have information, that query was successful but I don't see any return tows. There isn't any info how much rows was returned.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be one of those rare cases where using a CURSOR is truly the most appropriate, and performant option.

However, if performance is not a consideration, you could do a correlated subquery, like the following

```
SELECT *, second_time - first_time
   FROM
   (
      SELECT T.user, 
             T.date      AS first_time, 
             (SELECT MIN(S.date) 
                FROM My_Table S 
                WHERE S.user = T.user
                  AND S.date > T.date
             )                         AS second_time
        FROM My_Table T
   ) G
   WHERE (second_time - first_time) < 1300
```

This will run very slowly on large data sets.