# SQL SELECT rows where the difference between consecutive columns is less than X

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically [Mysql: Find rows, where timestamp difference is less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513983/mysql-find-rows-where-timestamp-difference-is-less-than-x), but I want to stop at the first value whose timestamp difference is larger than X.

I got so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         (LEAD(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)) - datetime AS difference 
  FROM history
) AS sq 
WHERE difference < '00:01:00'
```

Which seems to correctly return all rows where the difference between the row and the one "behind" it is less than a minute, but that means I still get large jumps in the `datetime`s, which I don't want - I want to select the most recent "run" of rows, where a "run" is defined as "the timestamps in `datetime` differ by less than a minute".

e.g., I have rows whose hypothetical timestamps are as follows:

```
24, 22, 21, 19, 18, 12, 11, 9, 7...
```

And my limit of differences is `3`, i.e. I want the run of the rows whose difference between "timestamps" is less than 3; therefore just:

```
24, 22, 21, 19, 18
```

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what are you asking, is my explanation not clear enough?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.  You have posted a query that works and then say that the results are not what you want.  What do you actually want?  Sample data would make this clear.

Comment: Does this edit make it clearer?

Comment: 11->9 and 9->7 are both less than 3... So, it's not clearer.

Comment: Exactly, but I don't want those because there's a jump of 18-12 = 5 in between.

Comment: But then how do you decide you want the 24->18 group and not the 12->7 group? Such inconsistencies imply you haven't finished working through all your test scenarios.

Comment: Because, as I've indicated in the question, it is the most recent group (in other words, the group with the highest timestamps).

Comment: Okay, then identify the first gap `>= n` and reuse that result to get everything earlier. (First using however postgres gets top row, I've seen that differ by dbms)

Comment: That makes sense, is this possible in a single query?

Comment: Yes, can take any query and use it as a sub-query with a alias to join/compare against. (E.g. `SELECT x FROM t WHERE t.y < (SELECT col FROM ...)`)

Comment: I think I've got enough pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to get the previous row's timestamp and check if the current row is within 3 minutes of it. Reset the group if the condition fails. After this grouping is done, you have the find the latest such group, use `max` to get it. Then get all those rows from the latest group.

Include a `partition by` clause in the window functions `lag`, `sum` and`max` if this has to be done for each id in the table.

```
with grps as (
select x.*,sum(col) over(order by dt) grp
from (select t.*
      --checking if the current row's timestamp is within 3 minutes of the next row
      ,case WHEN dt BETWEEN LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) 
       AND LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) + interval '3 minute' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END col
      from t) x
)
select dt 
from (select g.*,max(grp) over() maxgrp --getting the latest group
      from grps g
     ) g
where grp = maxgrp
```

The above would get you the members in the latest group even though it has one row. To avoid such results get the latest group which has more than 1 row.

```
with grps as (
select x.*,sum(col) over(order by dt) grp
from (select t.*
      ,case WHEN dt BETWEEN LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) 
       AND LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt) + 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END col
      from t) x
)
,grpcnts as (select g.*,count(*) over(partition by grp) grpcnt from grps g)
select dt from (select g.*,max(grp) over() maxgrp 
                from grpcnts g 
                where grpcnt > 1
               ) g 
where grp = maxgrp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a flag based on the `lead()` or `lag()` values.  I believe this does what you want:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM (SELECT h.*,
             SUM( (next_datetime < datetime + interval '1 minute')::int) OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) as grp
      FROM (SELECT h.*,
                   LEAD(h.datetime) OVER (ORDER BY h.datetime)) as next_datetime
            FROM history h
           ) h
      WHERE next_datetime < datetime + interval '1 hour'
     ) h
WHERE grp IS NULL OR grp = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved with [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) (this will select your rows one-by-one and stops when there is no row in range `interval '1 min'`):

```
with recursive h as (
    select * from (
      select   *
      from     history
      order by history.datetime desc
      limit    1
    ) s
  union all
    select * from (
      select   history.*
      from     h
      join     history on history.datetime >= h.datetime - interval '1 min'
      and      history.datetime < h.datetime
      order by history.datetime desc
      limit    1
    ) s
)
select * from h
```

This should be efficient if you have an index on `history.datetime`. Though, if you care about performance, you should test it against the window-function based ones. (I personally get a headache when see as much subqueries and window functions as needed for this problem. The irony in my answer is that postgresql does not support the `ORDER BY` clause directly inside recrursive CTEs, so I had to use 2 meaningless subqueries to "hide" them).

[rextester](http://rextester.com/IWY49058)